# Strange data access time in Azure Table Storage while using .Take()

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

this is our situation:

We store user messages in table Storage. The Partition key is the UserId and the RowKey is used as a message id.

When a users opens his message panel we want to just .Take(x) number of messages, we don't care about the sortOrder. But what we have noticed is that the time it takes to get the messages varies very much by the number of messages we take.

We did some small tests:
We did 50 * .Take(X) and compared the differences:
So we did .Take(1) 50 times and .Take(100) 50 times etc.

To make an extra check we did the same test 5 times.

Here are the results:

[image: Query Results]

As you can see there are some HUGE differences. The difference between 1 and 2 is very strange. The same for 199-200.

Does anybody have any clue how this is happening? The Table Storage is on a live server btw, not development storage.

Many thanks.

X: # Takes
Y: Test Number

**Update**
The problem only seems to come when I'm using a wireless network. But I'm using the cable the times are normal.

Comment: Have you watched the traffic via Fiddler or the like? Any chance you can share your test code and storage credentials with me? (Steve.Marx@microsoft.com)

Comment: I'll isolate the problem from my business app into a new project and mail it.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the data is collected in batches of a certain number x. When you request x+1 rows, it would have to take two batches and then drop a certain number.

Try running your test with increments of 1 as the Take() parameter, to confirm or dismiss this assumption.

Comment: If you look at .Take(1) and .Take(2), 99-100-101 the chance that it uses a batch is rather small. But thanks for the hint +1